# Как записать в файл json используя node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Стоит задача : Весь контент страницы, и прочая информация о настройках хранится в json файле.
Пользователь взаимодействует со страницей, меняет какие-то данные.
Все эти изменения записываются в файл json и файл json должен перезаписываться.

Можно ли реализовать запись в файл json прямо на клиенте, без взаимодействия с сервером? 
Если нет - подскажите пожалуйста API для взаимодействия с json файлом через node.js (express.js).
Если есть другие мысли по поводу - как это можно реализовать, буду рад советам.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Браузеры не работают с файловой системой создавая или редактируя файлы. Соответственно все сохранения делаются на сервере. Если вы не совсем понимаете основы взаимодействия сервера и клиента, вам будет сложно такое реализовать. Какой у вас есть опыт работы с AJAX, JSON, Node? Какая конкретно стоит перед вами задача?

Comment: Почему mongo не использовать?

Comment: larrymacbarry, у меня есть некоторый опыт работы с node, ajax, json. Как я и писал в своем вопросе - я не знаю какое API поможет мне в реализации.

Comment: Если в json нет секретной информации, которую надо скрывать от клиента, то можно хранить json, например, в localStorage:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Answer (score 1):

**NODE.JS**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dataJSON = ...;
fs.writeFile('file.json', dataJSON, function(){console.log('Error!');});
```